# Systems of equations and product of polynomials in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers

I'm scratching my head trying to represent and solve this 2 problems using linear algebra.

Almost immediately, any book I'm aware of, introduces vectors as a building block for matrices which in turn are a way to combine multiple vectors.

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
x - y = a \\
x + y = b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

this system can be easily $1:1$ mapped to 2 objects: 1 matrix and 1 column vector . $a$ and $b$ are scalars, $x$ and $y$ are the unknown .

But what is the most efficient way to represent a problem like

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
x + y = a \\
x \times y = b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

where there are $2$ scalars which express the sum and the product between $2$ unknown .

My real problems are about how to deal with multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$ using linear algebra objects.

$\langle\mathbb{R}^n,\times\rangle$ it's not commutative, in algebra you are used to several "tricks" which make your life easier and many of them are based on commutativity, apparently in linear algebra I still have problems in understanding how to deal with multiplication and how to translate such problems into vectors and matrices and I probably have to discard the idea of multiplication as just being a concatenation of multiple additions .

Another class of problems that I have problem representing with linear algebra objects is a product of polynomials, for example how to represent a product of binomials such as

$$(a + b)\times(a - b) = (a^2-b^2)$$

I'm not trying to pack to 2 things into 1 question, I think that they have something in common, they both deal with the underlying concept of multiplication, but if the 2 problems will differ significantly I'll dedicate another question for the last one because I'm really interested in getting this right .

The problem is that I can't visualize this given the limits of the operations between matrices and vectors, or just given the fact that the "real" linear operation is always a sum of elements, a multiplication looks like is something else and I'm having problems in understanding what that something else looks like .

Comment: When you say $\mathbb{R}^n, \times$ to you mean normal multiplication or cross product?  It seems like you mean normal multiplication in the rest of your question.  If so, then it is commutative...

Comment: @Goos I was considering the cross product, and the cross product is the closest thing for me, for now, to the algebraic concept of multiplication, for the simple fact that "internally" a matrix and a vector are linear because of sum operations between elements, I can't even think about relating the multiplication to another different concept for the time being, that's my main problem . mapping this problems and the concept of algebraic multiplication to linear algebra .

Comment: OK.  Actually, the cross product is really nothing like normal multiplication of real numbers.  It is something special to three dimensions.

Comment: @Goos I think I need some formalism because that is the "intuitive" part, but I still can't really compute the corresponding matrices and vectors to my problems . It feels like is a "multiplication full of corner cases", and I struggle with it. There are also tricks that make life easier but complicate the understanding of the formalism like multiplying by the inverse when you infact want to multiplicate 2 column vectors, which is often presented as a solution, but it's just a consequence of some properties that happen to work together, at least in a metric space .

Comment: @user2485710 The cross product really is NOT an analog of multiplication.  It is better seen as either relating to the Lie bracket on SU(2) or as a matrix.  Though it's presented that way in introductory Linear Algebra courses, it's not *really* a mapping from $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \mapsto \Bbb R^n$, because thing thing that comes out, *isn't really a vector*.  In fact, a closer analog of multiplication on vectors is the inner product (dot product), but that doesn't result in a vector, either.

Comment: Linear algebra really doesn't use cross products, it's just a helpful tool in solving some of the elementary geometric problems we come across in our first course in Linear Algebra. After that, basically the only time we worry about the cross product is when we want an easy way to compute a normal vector in $\Bbb R^3$. Don't think that it's any more useful than that -- unless you're studying Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

> Almost immediately, any book I'm aware of, introduces vectors as a building block for matrices which in turn are a way to combine multiple vectors.
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{l l}
> x - y = a \\
> x + y = b \\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   this system can be easily $1:1$ mapped to 2 objects: 1 matrix and 1 column vector . $a$ and $b$ are scalars, $x$ and $y$ are the unknown .

Right.  Linear algebra is designed well to handle this kind of problem.

> But what is the most efficient way to represent a problem like
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{l l}
> x + y = a \\
> x \times y = b \\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

This is not a system of *linear* equations, so the techniques of linear algebra do not directly apply.  What you have here is a system of polynomials in some number of variables, all set equal to zero.  There are many ways to approach this problem and I am no expert, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations) might be a good introduction.  In simple cases like the one above, one is taught to apply basic algebra and the quadratic formula.

> My real problems are about how to deal with multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$ using linear algebra objects.
>
> $\langle\mathbb{R}^n,\times\rangle$ it's not commutative, in algebra you are used to several "tricks" which make your life easier and many of them are based on commutativity, apparently in linear algebra I still have problems in understanding how to deal with multiplication and how to translate such problems into vectors and matrices and I probably have to discard the idea of multiplication as just being a concatenation of multiple additions .

Linear algebra does not study multiplication of real numbers; that is something closer to ring theory or analysis.  You cannot expect to translate any problem in which you solve an equation into linear algebra; linear algebra is just one (small) field of math and by no means does it have all the answers.  For instance it would be foolish to attempt to solve $\sin x = \frac12$ using linear algebra.

> Another class of problems that I have problem representing with linear algebra objects is a product of polynomials, for example how to represent a product of binomials such as
>
> $$(a + b)\times(a - b) = (a^2-b^2)$$

Linear algebra does not study polynomials.  If you want to study polynomials you should not be doing linear algebra.

> The problem is that I can't visualize this given the limits of the operations between matrices and vectors, or just given the fact that the "real" linear operation is always a sum of elements, a multiplication looks like is something else and I'm having problems in understanding what that something else looks like .

Right; the language of vectors does not obviously encapsulate the language of multiplication of real numbers.  Multiplication of vectors is called an inner product (dot product) and it's a different beast entirely.  Vectors will not help you visualize multiplication of scalar real numbers.